# CQWP not showning fields to display

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-query-web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part

My Content Query Web Part does not display anything under "fields to display"
[image]

I've been adding custom xsl:template

```
<xsl:template name='MyStyle' match="Row[@Style='MyStyle']" mode='itemstyle'>
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'><h3><xsl:value-of select='@MyTitle'/></h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img>
            <xsl:attribute name='src'>
                <xsl:value-of select='@MyLogo'/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            </img>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping='yes' select='@MySummary'/>
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping='yes' select='@MyDesc'/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

And It worked fine, but after I've made some more changes my troubles started.
So, I've delete ItemStyle.xsl with custom template and upload new "original" ItemStyle.xsl clear the cache from Sharepoint designer 2013.
But still problem not solved.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

In your root site go to Site Contents > Style Library > XSL Stylesheets and make sure the files are all checked in.